# Truck wont turn over and lights work battery is charged

Tags: ignition

I have a 2011 doge ram my lights and everything works besides the radio and the truck wont start you can hear it click when you turn it over but it won't start

Comment: MAybe a bad starter?

Comment: Does it crank or is it just a click? If it won't crank, it may be because of a bad starter. If it does crank, take a look at the fuel system. Check the fuse of the fuel pump, make sure you hear a hum when you turn the key to the run position. If you're running on gasoline, check the spark plugs. Maybe the fuel filter is clogged?